# Error : Internal Compiler Error when building UWP mobile app in azure dev-ops (release mode)

Tags: azure-devops, xamarin.uwp, build-pipeline

I get the following error when I build the UWP project in release mode through dev-ops build pipelines. The error states "Error : Internal Compiler Error" without giving a reason. When I build it in release mode locally using VS 2017 and VS 2019, it works fine. I'm using 64bit version of MSBuild.

Launching 'C:\Users\VssAdministrator.nuget\packages\runtime.win10-x64.microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.1.8\tools\x64\ilc\Tools64\nutc_driver.exe @"D:\a\1\s\Satellite\WindowsPhone10\obj\x64\release\ilc\intermediate\MDIL\Satellite.UWP.rsp"'

### [error]C:\Users\VssAdministrator.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.1.8\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(788,5): Error : Internal Compiler Error

C:\Users\VssAdministrator.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.1.8\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(788,5): error : Internal Compiler Error [D:\a\1\s\Satellite\WindowsPhone10\Satellite.UWP.csproj]

### [error]C:\Users\VssAdministrator.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.1.8\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(788,5): Error : ILT0005: 'C:\Users\VssAdministrator.nuget\packages\runtime.win10-x64.microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.1.8\tools\x64\ilc\Tools64\nutc_driver.exe @"D:\a\1\s\Satellite\WindowsPhone10\obj\x64\release\ilc\intermediate\MDIL\Satellite.UWP.rsp"' returned exit code 1

C:\Users\VssAdministrator.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.1.8\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(788,5): error : ILT0005: 'C:\Users\VssAdministrator.nuget\packages\runtime.win10-x64.microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.1.8\tools\x64\ilc\Tools64\nutc_driver.exe @"D:\a\1\s\Satellite\WindowsPhone10\obj\x64\release\ilc\intermediate\MDIL\Satellite.UWP.rsp"' returned exit code 1 [D:\a\1\s\Satellite\WindowsPhone10\Satellite.UWP.csproj]
Done Building Project "D:\a\1\s\Satellite\WindowsPhone10\Satellite.UWP.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

The project builds fine locally in VS 2017/2019 in both debug and release mode. We started getting the following error:

Error : Error: NUTC300F:Internal Compiler Error: Native compilation failed due to out of memory error

This error was happening locally in VS and also in Dev-Ops as well. In order to fix this issue, we stared using the 64bit version of MSBuild by embedding true in the release configuration. This fixed the release build locally, but it started giving me "Error : Internal Compiler Error" without an ounce of information. So not sure what's going on. It seems that there is a problem with the Dev-Ops build because I'm using the same configuration locally and it works.

Answer (score 0):

> Error: NUTC300F:Internal Compiler Error: Native compilation failed due to out of memory error

In general, the nutc_driver crashes are often due to the compiler running out of memory.

That is the reason why it failed without giving a reason. And you also got the error message:

> Native compilation failed due to out of memory error

So, the cause of this issue may be insufficient memory on hosted agent. Because Microsoft-hosted agents are Azure Virtual Machines, generally, Standard_DS2_v2 (2 vCPU, **7GB RAM**) according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops).

To resolve this issue, you can [setup your private agent](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-set-up-a-private-agent-in-visual-studio-tea) to execute your build pipeline.

Hope this helps.